# Spotify's script not working with reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, spotify

I was trying to link the spotify's script to my component, but when i do that with "useEffect" the window doesn't recognize the "onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady" property.The error is: "property onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady does not exist on type 'Window & typeOf globalThis'".How i solve it ?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function SpotifyPlayer() {

    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js";
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      return () => {
          document.body.removeChild(script);
        }
      }, []);

    window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
       // You can now initialize Spotify.Player and use the SDK
    }; 
      
}

export default SpotifyPlayer;
```

The component it's in a folder and the public html is in another.

[Image of folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWCmn.png)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I just saw that this `window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady` is a function you are binding on the window to execute when the spotify script is loaded.

Even easier. You just have to make sure you also call this from inside the useEffect hook:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function SpotifyPlayer() {

  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
      // do your spotify magic here.
    }
  }, []);
      
}

export default SpotifyPlayer;
```

Comment: I tried it and it works. Do you have the version of my code after I edited? Did you make sure to put the window.on... inside the useEffect hook?

Comment: Yes, i just paste the code, but look, as i  showed in the image above, this code it's just a tsx file without HTML, the HTML file is in another folder, i mean, this have anything to do?

Comment: A .jsx/.tsx file always has to return some "markup". If you want to isolate the logic from the UI, you have to refactor it into a custom hook.